# Could not compile c++ program with threads support on AIX with GCC compiler 4.7.3

Tags: c++, multithreading, gcc, aix

I have problem when compiling code below on aix machine with gcc compiler (version 4.7.3):

*SomeThread.h*

```
#ifndef SomeThread_H
#define SomeThread_H

class SomeThread {

   public:

      SomeThread(void);

      virtual ~SomeThread(void);

      void runThread();

};    // SomeThread

#endif // _SomeThread_H_
```

*SomeThread.cpp*

```
#include "SomeThread.h"
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

namespace {
void foo_thread_function() {
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
      cout << "Some threaded text" << endl;
   }
}
}

SomeThread::SomeThread() {
}    // SomeThread

SomeThread::~SomeThread() {
}    // ~SomeThread


void SomeThread::runThread() {
   thread foo_thread_01(foo_thread_function);
   thread foo_thread_02(foo_thread_function);
   thread foo_thread_03(foo_thread_function);

   foo_thread_01.join();
   foo_thread_02.join();
   foo_thread_03.join();
}
```

The error which I get is following:

```
SomeThread.cpp: In member function 'void SomeThread::runThread()':
SomeThread.cpp:58:4: error: reference to 'thread' is ambiguous
In file included from /usr/include/sys/ptrace.h:28:0,
                 from /usr/include/sys/proc.h:42,
                 from /usr/include/sys/pri.h:43,
                 from /usr/include/sys/sched.h:38,
                 from /usr/include/sched.h:51,
                 from /opt/freeware/lib/gcc/powerpc-ibm-aix7.1.0.0/4.7.3/include-fixed/pthread.h:76,
                 from /opt/freeware/lib/gcc/powerpc-ibm-aix7.1.0.0/4.7.3/include/c++/powerpc-ibm-aix7.1.0.0/pthread/ppc64/bits/gthr-posix.h:41,
                 from /opt/freeware/lib/gcc/powerpc-ibm-aix7.1.0.0/4.7.3/include/c++/powerpc-ibm-aix7.1.0.0/pthread/ppc64/bits/gthr-default.h:30,
                 from /opt/freeware/lib/gcc/powerpc-ibm-aix7.1.0.0/4.7.3/include/c++/powerpc-ibm-aix7.1.0.0/pthread/ppc64/bits/gthr.h:150,
                 from /opt/freeware/lib/gcc/powerpc-ibm-aix7.1.0.0/4.7.3/include/c++/ext/atomicity.h:34,
                 from /opt/freeware/lib/gcc/powerpc-ibm-aix7.1.0.0/4.7.3/include/c++/memory:75,
                 from /opt/freeware/lib/gcc/powerpc-ibm-aix7.1.0.0/4.7.3/include/c++/thread:40,
                 from SomeThread.cpp:5:
/usr/include/sys/thread.h:105:8: error: candidates are: struct thread
In file included from SomeThread.cpp:5:0:
/opt/freeware/lib/gcc/powerpc-ibm-aix7.1.0.0/4.7.3/include/c++/thread:60:9: error:                 class std::thread
SomeThread.cpp:58:11: error: expected ';' before 'foo_thread_01'
SomeThread.cpp:59:4: error: reference to 'thread' is ambiguous
In file included from /usr/include/sys/ptrace.h:28:0,
                 from /usr/include/sys/proc.h:42,
                 from /usr/include/sys/pri.h:43,
                 from /usr/include/sys/sched.h:38,
                 from /usr/include/sched.h:51,
                 from /opt/freeware/lib/gcc/powerpc-ibm-aix7.1.0.0/4.7.3/include-fixed/pthread.h:76,
                 from /opt/freeware/lib/gcc/powerpc-ibm-aix7.1.0.0/4.7.3/include/c++/powerpc-ibm-aix7.1.0.0/pthread/ppc64/bits/gthr-posix.h:41,
                 from /opt/freeware/lib/gcc/powerpc-ibm-aix7.1.0.0/4.7.3/include/c++/powerpc-ibm-aix7.1.0.0/pthread/ppc64/bits/gthr-default.h:30,
                 from /opt/freeware/lib/gcc/powerpc-ibm-aix7.1.0.0/4.7.3/include/c++/powerpc-ibm-aix7.1.0.0/pthread/ppc64/bits/gthr.h:150,
                 from /opt/freeware/lib/gcc/powerpc-ibm-aix7.1.0.0/4.7.3/include/c++/ext/atomicity.h:34,
                 from /opt/freeware/lib/gcc/powerpc-ibm-aix7.1.0.0/4.7.3/include/c++/memory:75,
                 from /opt/freeware/lib/gcc/powerpc-ibm-aix7.1.0.0/4.7.3/include/c++/thread:40,
                 from SomeThread.cpp:5:
```

I compile the above files with following command line:

```
g++ -maix64 -DTARGET=target_thread -DGENDATE=04_01_2017 -DTT_LIB_DLLSUFFIX=\".so\" -DOSNAME=\"AIX\" -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_REENTRANT -DAIX -Wno-deprecated -I.  -std=gnu++11   -maix64 -pthread   -mminimal-toc  -fpermissive -Wno-write-strings -Winvalid-offsetof   -O3  -c -oSomeThread.o SomeThread.cpp
```

Comment: Pretty sure fixincludes are not up to date for AIX 7.1.  You need gcc 4.8.3-1.  http://www.perzl.org/aix/index.php?n=Main.Gcc

Comment: @stark: On Linux we are using gcc version 4.7.1 and there everything is ok. Very strange behaviour.

Comment: Doesn't work with g++-4.8.3 either (AIX-6.1) (If you want a working program, you might want to use C-language with pthreads)

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond: The solution is to write `std::thread` instead of just `thread`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that there are multiple implementations of `thread` with your compiler options and includes. Maybe it would be just enough to correct the code to this.
SomeThread.cpp

```
#include "SomeThread.h"
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

//Stop using namespace std, please
namespace SomeNamespace {
void foo_thread_function() {
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
      cout << "Some threaded text" << endl;
   }
}
}

SomeThread::SomeThread() {
}    // SomeThread

SomeThread::~SomeThread() {
}    // ~SomeThread


void SomeThread::runThread() {
   std::thread foo_thread_01(SomeNamespace::foo_thread_function);
   std::thread foo_thread_02(SomeNamespace::foo_thread_function);
   std::thread foo_thread_03(SomeNamespace::foo_thread_function);

   foo_thread_01.join();
   foo_thread_02.join();
   foo_thread_03.join();
}
```

Ambiguous means that there are multiple interpretations of the same word.
Example:

```
namespace Bla{
   struct SomeStruct{
   }
}

namespace Blub{
   struct SomeStruct{
   }
}

int main(){
   using namespace Bla;
   using namespace Blub;
   SomeStruct ImAmbiguous; // Problem now, which struct should the compiler choose now?
   Bla::SomeStruct structFromBla; //Now the compiler knows which struct should be choosen
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unnamed namespaces are perfectly valid.

Comment: Oh yes, I'm sorry. That's totally useless xD

Comment: "//Stop using namespace std, please" Why? It's not in a header.

Comment: Just don't like it, sorry. I prefer it using only for small bodies exactly because it could result in ambigious errors.

Comment: "error: reference to 'thread' is ambiguous" is in the log text. Am I wrong with that?

Comment: @ArthurM.: Your solution works on AIX. One should use `std::thread()` instead of just `thread` (regardless of using namespace std). There is probably another thread structure/function recognized by gcc which is not in std namespace. You can freely use function from unnamed namespace.

Comment: Haha yeah I noticed this too, I was thinking that wouldn't make any sense because instead I could just write the whole code outside of this namespace

Comment: @ArthurM.: Hehe this was a nice one I must agree. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: I should write a comment into the line saying "stop using empty namespace! " :D

Comment: The code I have written was just for a proof of concept for me that I can also use threads on AIX :). I know it is not so good written, but I learned some new things, so I will use them in the future :).